# wordpress added unwanted margin below footer

Tags: css, footer, margins

Nothing I found in the archives has worked for me, so hopefully you can help me find a solution.  I created my template in Dreamweaver, and have almost successfully transferred it all over to a wordpress theme, but now wordpress has added a small margin below the footer.

The margin doesn't appear on the original layout:
http://merrymeadowspagosa.com/post.html

But it IS on the template:
http://merrymeadowspagosa.com/

Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with wordpress. Pure css: your `body` element has a `padding-bottom` of 40px you need to remove. Inspect it with Chrome Dev Tools

Comment: oh jeez. Thank you!  Don't know where that came in to play!